# how to remove warning at top of console tab

Tags: google-chrome, console, google-chrome-devtools, warnings, opera

after I opened my console I saw some game added this into my console and I do not know how to remove it from entire browser

[image]

**Update** :

it will not remove by updating opera or reinstall it

it also shown when i delete all data from AppData/Roaming , AppData/Local

it also shown when i install another version of Opera Browser

answers said they add extension to terminate it . but it wont remove it just make it hide after installing .

so it can be on Registry and i delete all opera from there but it did not removed

Answer (score 2):

Apparently there are 2 ways to solve this problem.

1. CREATE AN EXTENSION TO KILL OPERA CONSOLE WARNING
2. Rollback to old version and disable update.

Both are described [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72462196/red-warning-message-in-opera-console)
If they don't work, you can try installing [Opera Developer.](https://www.opera.com/ru/computer/beta)
May be clean Registry with something like Reg Organizer before installing.

And yep, opera developers don't care at all.